# server issue with AWS elastic IP ,when i came run on web browser

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, xampp

I had used the xampp server for my aws virtual server .In my virtual server all of the thing working well (run on localhost successfully .), however, I used the browser my elastic IP is not working well or error showing (this site can not reach ). anybody tell me what is the issue that it is working on my virtual server but not in url when I used the IP or domain of my virtual server.

Comment: did you make sure that you have open the port (probably 80 or 443) in security group of your ec2 server.

Comment: I got answer .It was a firewall security problem .

Comment: can you please tell me why my vote is going down .

Comment: If it was me Apology, may be an UN-intentional click